# Load Classes and call Functions dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf

I have around 80 -90 classes in my project, each class is having one function which calculates and return some value.

Imaginary Class Names -> AAB, AAC .... ZZZ

They have function like:  CalAAB(double [] param1 , int param2).. and so on for every class.

I am planing to make one program to create one program where user can select any one or two classes and some operation / calculation will be done through function of user selected class.

I can achieve above task with help of If else and even with help of switch but that is restricting me to make complex queries by mixing 3-4 classes and program will be too lengthy.

**Is it possible that I save name of these classes and functions into text file and then load classes and function according to user's choice.**

My Major requirement is how to execute below line

```
ClassName cname = new ClassName(); 

double [] result = cname.FunctionName(Param1, Param2);
```

Where ClassName and FunctionName will be loaded from text file as string

Comment: It *sounds* like what you're going for is [reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183.aspx). Have you looked into that at all?

Comment: Yes, this is possible. Please don't ask us to write the code for you though - Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Instead you should look into methods like `Assembly.LoadFile`, `Activator.CreateInstanceFrom`, etc, to see if you can figure it out. If you get stuck post your code and we can help.

Comment: I never asked for code , just need some idea

Comment: @MatthewHaugen I would suggest using `dynamic`.

Comment: All the reflection methods you will need will be Assembly.Load, Type.GetType(string typname), Type.GetConstructor, Type.GetMethod.  If the classes are in different assemblies you will need Assembly.Load.  You can store the Full Type names in a text file and use Type.GetType to load them.  One you have the Type object you can use Type.GetMethod and then MethodInfo.Invoke to call it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use Reflection. Something like this..

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile("YourAssembly.dll");
Type type = assembly.GetType("NameSpace.AAB"); 
var aabInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(type, null);
MethodInfo methodInfo = type.GetMethod("CalAAB");
var result = methodInfo.Invoke(classInstance, param1, param2);
```